# Origine dell’espressione “all’addiaccio”

Tags: word-usage, etymology, phrase-origin

Secondo  [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/addiaccio/) il principale significato di addiaccio è:

> Spazio cinto di rete nel quale il gregge è tenuto di notte allo scoperto: Pecoraio, ti cercano all’addiaccio. (D’Annunzio).

da cui deriva l’uso più comune con significato “all’aperto” in espressioni come:

> stare all’addiaccio, passare la notte all’addiaccio, dormire all’addiaccio.

Ma come nota il sito “[Una parola al giorno](https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/addiaccio)”:

> Questa parola è ingannevole: il fatto che dormire all'addiaccio significhi dormire all'aperto, e che quando si dorme all'aperto si debba spesso fare i conti col freddo, ci fa ricondurre intuitivamente l'addiaccio al ghiaccio. Idea non troppo peregrina, visto che in certi vernacoli toscani 'diaccio' è proprio una variante di 'ghiaccio'.
>   Ma fuor di locuzione l'addiaccio è un'altra cosa, e ci racconta un'immagine precisa e non direttamente collegata col freddo.

Entrambe le fonti danno come  etimologia il termine latino “*adiacere*” ossia giacere accanto.

Ma da dove  deriva il senso di “dormire all’aperto” che dà  comunque l’idea di dormire al freddo?

Comment: Quindi, la domanda sarebbe come si è passato da "giacere accanto" a "dormire all'aperto"?

Comment: @Charo - mi chiedo quale sia l’origine del termine e del suo significato.

Comment: Ma l'etimologia del termine sarebbe il latino *adiacēre*, no?

Comment: Ora non trovo una fonte, ma credo di ricordare che si riferisca ai soldati (e forse anche agli animali?) che, in mancanza di un accampamento, dormono sdraiati uno accanto all'altro. Spero di ritrovare dove lo lessi, ammesso che fosse una fonte seria, e sperando che nel frattempo qualcuno trovi anche di meglio.

Comment: @Charo - sì, ma dormire accanto (adiacere) non significa dormire all’aperto, e all’addiaccio significa all’aperto, esposto alle intemperie.